# Is it possible to create real time custom object detection using React Native?

Tags: react-native, tensorflow-lite

I want to do this without using recognition on server or on cloud. I already trained tensorflow-lite model. I've seen tflite-react-native but it works only with images not real time camera streaming. I'm wandering if it's even possible to make capturing and recognition custom object in real time without streaming the video on backend. Any advices and thoughts are very appreciated.